# VBA Copy/Paste Dynamic Range from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am trying to copy data from `wsCL2` in Column `A` starting from cell `A2` down to whenever the data ends; the number of rows can vary.

I want to paste into Column `A` of `coSummary`, from the next empty cell in that column.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCL2 As Worksheet
    Dim summary As Worksheet
    Dim colLastRow As Long
    Dim summaryLastRow As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCL2 = wb.Sheets("Tocopyfrom")
    Set summary = wb.Sheets("Summary")

    'Defining last row of data in Colliers
    summaryLastRow = summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colLastRow = wsCL2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    summary.Cells(10, 10).Value = colLastRow
    summary.Cells(11, 10).Value = summaryLastRow

    'Copying range from Colliers to Summary Page  (***ERROR HERE***)
    wsCL2.Range(Cells(2, "A").Address(), Cells(colLastRow, "A")) _
        .Copy summary.Cells(summaryLastRow + 1, "A")

    colLastRow = summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

It sometimes throws an error when trying the `Copy` method; other times it will execute properly.

I suspect it's related to refreshing the values for the `summaryLastRow` value or to `D`?

Thanks!

Comment: ...which error?

Comment: This `.Address()` should be removed

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in this line of code:

```
wsCL2.Range(Cells(2, "A").Address(), Cells(colLastRow, "A")).Copy summary.Cells(summaryLastRow + 1, "A")
```

You use a lot of "Cells" which do not reference to wsCL2 but to your ActiveSheet, which is probably not what you want.
This is the correct way to do it:

```
wsCL2.Range(wsCL2.Cells(2, "A").Address(), wsCL2.Cells(colLastRow, "A")).Copy summary.Cells(summaryLastRow + 1, "A")
```

For better understanding, this is what your code is actually saying:

```
wsCL2.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "A").Address(), ActiveSheet.Cells(colLastRow, "A")).Copy summary.Cells(summaryLastRow + 1, "A")
```

Edit: I'm also not sure about how you're using these references
once with .Address: Cells(2, "A").Address()
and next up without: Cells(colLastRow, "A")
A better way to reference ranges in my opinion is by using just digits:

```
wsCL2.Range( wsCL2.Cells(2,1), wsCL2.Cells(colLastRow,1) )
```

**Final Edit:**
One other thing, if you're tired of writing wsCL2.

```
with wsCl2
  .Range( .Cells(2,1), .Cells(colLastRow,1) )
end with
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very prompt response, I'll give it a go and get back to you!

Comment: Wow that's absolutely amazing! It works perfectly now, thank you for the great explanation of what was going wrong with the code!

Comment: An "accepted answer" marking would be nice :-)
I've also added another info/code snippet into my post above.